# XSLT confusion using template matches and variable names

Tags: xml, xslt

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1afe3959274d49233854

I am trying to transform my xml file I am learning with into a html table and am doing ok so far but am a little confused with linking elements back to ids. I included the code in the gist link above. Beat my head against it, but have been getting different, but incorrect results each time. Does anyone see what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could declare your variable right after your first loop

```
<xsl:for-each select="dronecollection/drones/dronetype">
    <xsl:variable name="sizeid" select="@s_id"/>
    ...
```

then select the value that matches the `s_id` of your target node, such as:

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::drones/following-sibling::modelsize/size[@s_id=$sizeid]/description"/>
```

with your input XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="drones_list.xsl" ?>-->
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="drones_tabular.xsl" ?>
<dronecollection>
    <drones>
        <dronetype d_id="_1" t_id="_01" s_id="_001">
            <model_name>Phantom 3</model_name>
            <price>699</price>
            <flighttime_min>17</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>20</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_2" t_id="_01" s_id="_002">
            <model_name>Inspire 1</model_name>
            <price>2899</price>
            <flighttime_min>18</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>20</flighttime_max>

        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_3" t_id="_02" s_id="_001">
            <model_name>Q500 4K</model_name>
            <price>1300</price>
            <flighttime_min>20</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>25</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_4" t_id="_03" s_id="_001">
            <model_name>Solo</model_name>
            <price>999</price>
            <flighttime_min>20</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>25</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_5" t_id="_04" s_id="_004">
            <model_name>X4</model_name>
            <price>45</price>
            <flighttime_min>5</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>7</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_6" t_id="_05" s_id="_004">
            <model_name>Blade Nano QX</model_name>
            <price>90</price>
            <flighttime_min>5</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>7</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_7" t_id="_06" s_id="_003">
            <model_name>Bebop</model_name>
            <price>499</price>
            <flighttime_min>8</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>10</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_8" t_id="_07" s_id="_003">
            <model_name>TBS GEMINI</model_name>
            <price>600</price>
            <flighttime_min>5</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>8</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_9" t_id="_03" s_id="_001">
            <model_name>IRIS</model_name>
            <price>740</price>
            <flighttime_min>10</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>15</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

        <dronetype d_id="_10" t_id="_03" s_id="_002">
            <model_name>X8</model_name>
            <price>1300</price>
            <flighttime_min>12</flighttime_min>
            <flighttime_max>17</flighttime_max>
        </dronetype>

    </drones>

    <manufacturer_type>
        <type t_id="_01">
            <manufacturer>DJI</manufacturer>
        </type>
        <type t_id="_02">
            <manufacturer>Yuneec</manufacturer>
        </type>
        <type t_id="_03">
            <manufacturer>3DR Robotics</manufacturer>
        </type>
        <type t_id="_04">
            <manufacturer>Hubsan</manufacturer>
        </type>
        <type t_id="_05">
            <manufacturer>Horizon Hobby</manufacturer>
        </type>
        <type t_id="_06">
            <manufacturer>Parrot</manufacturer>
        </type>
        <type t_id="_07">
            <manufacturer>Team BlackSheep</manufacturer>
        </type>
    </manufacturer_type>

    <modelsize>
        <size s_id="_001">
            <description>Medium</description>
        </size>
        <size s_id="_002">
            <description>Large</description>
        </size>
        <size s_id="_003">
            <description>Small</description>
        </size>
        <size s_id="_004">
            <description>Very Small</description>
        </size>
    </modelsize>
</dronecollection>
```

and this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <h2>XSLT Transformation</h2>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
                        <th>Manufacturer</th>
                        <th>Model Name</th>
                        <th>Estimated Price ($)</th>
                        <th>Flight Time (min)</th>
                        <th>Model Size</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="dronecollection/drones/dronetype">
                        <xsl:variable name="sizeid" select="@s_id"/>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:apply-templates select="model_name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="model_name"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="flighttime_min"/>
                                <xsl:text> to </xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="flighttime_max"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ancestor::drones/following-sibling::modelsize/size[@s_id=$sizeid]/description"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

the output is

```
<html>
   <body>
      <h2>XSLT Transformation</h2>
      <table border="1">
         <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Manufacturer</th>
            <th>Model Name</th>
            <th>Estimated Price ($)</th>
            <th>Flight Time (min)</th>
            <th>Model Size</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Phantom 3</td>
            <td>Phantom 3</td>
            <td>699</td>
            <td>17 to 20</td>
            <td>Medium</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Inspire 1</td>
            <td>Inspire 1</td>
            <td>2899</td>
            <td>18 to 20</td>
            <td>Large</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Q500 4K</td>
            <td>Q500 4K</td>
            <td>1300</td>
            <td>20 to 25</td>
            <td>Medium</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Solo</td>
            <td>Solo</td>
            <td>999</td>
            <td>20 to 25</td>
            <td>Medium</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>X4</td>
            <td>X4</td>
            <td>45</td>
            <td>5 to 7</td>
            <td>Very Small</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Blade Nano QX</td>
            <td>Blade Nano QX</td>
            <td>90</td>
            <td>5 to 7</td>
            <td>Very Small</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Bebop</td>
            <td>Bebop</td>
            <td>499</td>
            <td>8 to 10</td>
            <td>Small</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>TBS GEMINI</td>
            <td>TBS GEMINI</td>
            <td>600</td>
            <td>5 to 8</td>
            <td>Small</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>IRIS</td>
            <td>IRIS</td>
            <td>740</td>
            <td>10 to 15</td>
            <td>Medium</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>X8</td>
            <td>X8</td>
            <td>1300</td>
            <td>12 to 17</td>
            <td>Large</td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```